# get value from count() in Criteria Api

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql, criteria-api

Can anyone help me to find a solution.
I want to check if count method equals to 0 or not.

```
private Expression<Long> countProductReviewRatings(CriteriaBuilder cb, Join<Product, ProductReview> joinProductReview) {
    return cb.count(toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(cb, joinProductReview));
}
```

this is the example of code I want to run

here is method it uses

```
private Expression<BigDecimal> toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(CriteriaBuilder cb, Join<Product, ProductReview> joinProductReview) {
    return cb.selectCase()
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.FIVE), Rating.FIVE.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.FOUR_AND_HALF), Rating.FOUR_AND_HALF.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.FOUR), Rating.FOUR.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.THREE_AND_HALF), Rating.THREE_AND_HALF.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.THREE), Rating.THREE.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.TWO_AND_HALF), Rating.TWO_AND_HALF.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.TWO), Rating.TWO.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.ONE_AND_HALF), Rating.ONE_AND_HALF.getNumericValue())
            .when(cb.equal(joinProductReview.get(ProductReview_.RATING), Rating.ONE), Rating.ONE.getNumericValue())
            .otherwise(0)
            .as(BigDecimal.class);
```

Here is another method

```
    private Expression<Long> countProductDefaultRatings(CriteriaBuilder cb, Join<Product, ProductDefaultRating> joinProductDefaultRating) {
    return cb.count(joinProductDefaultRating.get(ProductDefaultRating_.DEFAULT_AVG_RATING));
}
```

And here I run this methods

```
    private Expression<Double> calculateAverageRating(CriteriaBuilder cb, Join<Product, ProductReview> joinProductReview,
                                                  Join<Product, ProductDefaultRating> joinProductDefaultRating) {

    var countProductReviewRatings = countProductReviewRatings(cb, joinProductReview);
    var countProductDefaultRatings = countProductDefaultRatings(cb, joinProductDefaultRating);

    if (countProductReviewRatings.isNotNull().isNegated() &&
            countProductDefaultRatings.isNull().isNegated()) {
        return cb.quot(cb.sum(toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(cb, joinProductReview)), countProductReviewRatings).as(Double.class);
    }
    if (countProductReviewRatings.isNull().isNegated() &&
            countProductDefaultRatings.isNotNull().isNegated()) {
        return cb.quot(cb.sum(joinProductDefaultRating.get(ProductDefaultRating_.DEFAULT_AVG_RATING)), countProductDefaultRatings).as(Double.class);
    }
    if (countProductReviewRatings.isNotNull().isNegated() &&
            countProductDefaultRatings.isNotNull().isNegated()) {
        return cb.quot(cb.sum(cb.quot(cb.sum(toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(cb, joinProductReview)), countProductReviewRatings),
                cb.quot(cb.sum(joinProductDefaultRating.get(ProductDefaultRating_.DEFAULT_AVG_RATING)), countProductDefaultRatings)), 2).as(Double.class);
    }

    CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce<Object> coalesce = cb.coalesce();
    coalesce.value(countProductReviewRatings);
    coalesce.value(countProductDefaultRatings);
    coalesce.value(0);
    return coalesce.as(Double.class);
}
```

The main purpose is to count average rating that depend on are they present or not and to order by this average rating

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the cb to create a nullif test.
`CriteriaBuilder.nullif​(Expression<Y> x, Y y)`

```
Long v = cb.nullif​(cb.count(toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(cb, joinProductReview)), L0); //This will be null if count is 0

if (v==null){
      ** do something
    }
```

From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/index.html?javax/persistence/criteria/class-use/Expression.html